# Are SHAP feature importance measures biased towards variables with many potential cut points?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, importance, shapley-value

Variable importance measures in Random Forests can be biased towards variables with more categories, even using permutation-based methods:

https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-8-25

Does this also apply to feature importance as measured by SHAP (in eg xgboost)?